# How to create a test query from a function?

Tags: mysql

Having trouble producing more than one row from this query. I want to include more samples in my test query. Maybe 2 more names to test so that my output. I think I could use UNION ALL but not sure.

This consist of 3 columns and 1 row, but I want 2 more samples adding 2 more rows:

```
 select tstName, AnticipatedValue, a_testbed.NameFormat('F', 'Clark', 'John') as  "name"
 from (
   select 'Clark, John' as tstName, 'John Clark' as AnticipatedValue ) as tstTbl#
```

The function has three input parameters. The first is a 'F' which formats names as firstName lastName, the second and third parameters are strings which are the last and first names.

Answer (score 0):

you could accomplish with `UNION`

```
SELECT tstName, AnticipatedValue,
    a_testbed.NameFormat('F', firstName, lastName) as  "name"
FROM (
   SELECT 'Clark1' AS firstName, 'John1' as lastName, 'John Clark' as AnticipatedValue 
   UNION
   SELECT 'Clark2' AS firstName, 'John2' as lastName, 'John Clark' as AnticipatedValue 
   UNION
   SELECT 'Clark3' AS firstName, 'John3' as lastName, 'John Clark' as AnticipatedValue 
   ) AS tstTbl#
```

Comment: Still not working. The results in the last column all display John Clark. I need the other columns to reflect all changes. Example:  AClark, John results John AClark and so on.